# Deleting path portion from each line in a text file list

Tags: batch-processing

From command prompt, how can I delete all the path information in each line in a text file, and keep only the filename & extension.

Eg. this is my text file:

```
d:\hvsc\GAMES\0-9\4x4_Off-Road_Racing.sid  
d:\hvsc\GAMES\S-Z\Wizardry.sid  
d:\hvsc\MUSICIANS\R\Rayden\Wizardry_96.sid  
d:\hvsc\MUSICIANS\D\DRAX\Wizzkid.sid  
d:\hvsc\DEMOS\G-L\Genias-Logo.sid  
d:\hvsc\GAMES\S-Z\World_Games.sid  
d:\hvsc\MUSICIANS\B\Blues_Muz\Gallefoss_Glenn\Countdown_To_Nil.sid  
d:\hvsc\MUSICIANS\S\Sphere_Chromance\Fighting_the_green.sid  
d:\hvsc\MUSICIANS\W\Whittaker_David\Wrath_of_the_Demon.sid
```

But I only want this:

```
4x4_Off-Road_Racing.sid  
Wizardry.sid  
Wizardry_96.sid  
etc
```

Comment: Welcome at stackoverflow. Unfortunately, there is no _write code for me_ service. Read [ask]. Hint: read entire `for /?`, There is `%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only`...

Comment: I've experimented with for and tokens but couldn't work it out.

Comment: Try `for /F "delims=" %I in (yourfile.txt) do @echo %~nxI` from command line; to use it in a batch script, double all the `%`s (use  `%%I` and `%%~nxI`)